# How do I remove keyboard shortcuts from an application?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Example, in NetNewsWire there is a keyboard shortcut to mark a page as read and a hidden keyboard shortcut that marks all items from that feed as read. I accidentally hit both often. How can I block the keyboard shortcuts from working?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to change the keyboard shortcuts, just remove the ones you don't want to use.

I believe it's in Help > Keyboard Shortcuts

*edit*

hmm I haven't used NNW in a long time but now that I think about it I'm not sure if there is a way to remap the keys...

You could however use [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) (not freeware) to remap the keys but I doubt you'll want to buy software to do that...

Other than that I don't think it's possible...

Comment: That just lists the keyboard shortcuts that aren't in the menubar. No way to change them.

Comment: You can't change anything the application doesn't let you change.